# Debugging Method in Chrome: Identify what line of code is executed after Onload event ended

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, onload

I have a function in javascript. For example:

```
function Sample(){
    var myid_signature_image  = new Image(); 
    myid_signature_image.onload = function () {                              
        alert('Two');                                                                                                                           
    }; 
    alert('One');
}
```

I put a breakpoint in each line of the function. `One` is being displayed first, and then `Two`. Afer the `onload` event, some javascript function is interfering my code. How will I know what line of code is it using `Google Chrome Developer Tools`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fire up Developer Tools (`Ctrl + Shift + I`) and under Sources tab, put a breakpoint at the `alert('Two');` line.  Carry out your html actions thru the browser, in this case `onload` needs a refresh, and it will halt on the breakpoint.  From here, just press `F10` (step over next function call) and it will tell you what lines are executed next after your `onload` event.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **[timeline](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/timeline)** of Chrome DevTools.

Filter out the purple (rendering) and green (painting) events as that is not what you are interested in.

You can programmatically add a marker in the timeline by using `console.timeStamp("Marker name");`. That might help you find the time range:

```
myid_signature_image.onload = function () {
    console.timeStamp("Image loaded");
};
```

The mark will be rendered in the timeline as a small colored bar, provided the *Flame Chart* view is not activated. Mouse over it to see the timestamp label. You can also user the search box so as to find the event. See capture below:

[image]

Once you found the event corresponding to the javascript executed after the image load event, you can jump to the script line of code from there.

Comment: +1 for you, for giving me an idea. Anyways I cant see the timestamp "Image loaded" in my timeline . Where do I locate it? Im sure that the code where I put console.timeStamp("Image loaded"); has been executed.

Comment: I added a screeshot for better visualization